# Digraphs Missing for Greek Letters

Tags: digraphs

A co-worker built a version of gvim 9 that I'm running in the two environments below with the differing results:

1. A VM that I have a VNC open to. Here the Greek letter digraphs work great. I'm using the `Fira Mono Medium` font.
2. Another VM that I forward the X display to the VM above. They use the same repos, but have some different installed software. In this case when I do `:digraph` the list is shorter and the Greek letters aren't present. The digraphs in my files show some jumbled characters, *despite having the same fonts installed* and using them.

Any ideas on what I might be missing here? It's the same executable file, compiled the same way. But the `:digraph` command shows much different results with the same font.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. What is VNC? What does it have to do with vim? Are you compiling vim separately on each machine or merely copying/sharing the executable between them? Expand on your problems with clear reproducible steps/actions, please. Also, see if `:h digraph-table` contains your greek symbols.

Comment: See below, I figured out the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that, for some reason, the `encoding` and `fileencodings` are different between the two environments. If I force `encoding=utf-8` it seems to work fine.

Comment: check the output of `locale`/`:language` between the two systems.

Comment: Thanks, @D.BenKnoble! That seems to point to the issue. It looks like changing the `LANG` variable in my `.bash_profile` will allow me to use the utf8 locale.